# How to center a (dynamically resizeable) image-map with the imagemapster plug-in

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I'm using the JQuery-plugin [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) and the code from the authors example at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/jQG48 I am able to dynamically resize my imagemap. Now I am trying to center my imagemap horizontally on my page, but I cant get it working. 
What I have tried so far: adding CSS styles `margin-left:auto`  and `margin-right:auto` to my image tag.

any help /hint? thanks

Comment: Create you own example with JSFiddle. It will be much easier to help you out if we have something to troubleshoot and review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 0**

I was able to update the imagemapster author's example and obtain the desired result.

**CSS**

```
#mapster_wrap_0 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jQG48/399/.

`​mapster_wrap_0` looks auto-generated so there might be a cleaner way to accomplish this centering.

**Solution 1**

Creating a wrapper div around your map appears to work as well.

```
<div id="MapWrapper" style="margin:auto; width:75%;">
    <img src="https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/raw/master/examples/images/usa_map_720.png" 
usemap="#usa">
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jQG48/400/.

Comment: addendum: solution 0 works in firefox and opera, not in ie9. solution 1 does not work in any of the tree browsers

Comment: Those solutions should point you in a direction to get a cross browser solution.

Comment: addendum2:solution 0 by JSuar plus the following wrapper around the image seems to work in ie9, firefox and opera. wrapper:<div style="text-align:center">  imagemap here </div>